# Landscape mode without a ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios4, landscape

I have a project based on a window-template, so it doesn't have a viewController. Now I'm trying to make this work in landscape only, and I have set the "supported device orientations" to "Landscape (right home button)" only, just the way I want it. The app actually launches in Landscape mode, but when I want to show an image which is btw a landscape-fullscreen one, iOS draws it in Portrait mode, cutting off what doesn't fit. Well I know the option of implementing a ViewController and editing the "shouldAutorotate..." method, but I want to do it without.
I have one solution in my mind, but I'm not sure whether it#s such a great idea: Rotate the whole coordinate-system on app-startup manually using "CGTransform..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Down that path lies madness.  Just because the template doesn't include a built-in `UIViewController` doesn't mean you can't add one yourself.

Add one, and save yourself a bazillion headaches.

From a more technical standpoint, a lot a UIKit *expects* the window to have a `UIViewController`, and not having one means you can lose out on a whole lot of behavior that you would otherwise get for free.